# Homogenic Linear System Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

I need help approaching this question,
any help will be much appreciated.

Assume that a linear system exists over $\Bbb{R}$ so that its solution group is:
$$S=\{(a,a^2,b)|a,b \in \Bbb{R}\}$$
Prove that system is homogenic

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is $R\,$?

Comment: The real numbers

Comment: Drnote it in  a standard way ($\Bbb R$ or $\mathbf R$). It is quite common to denote a ring as $R$.

Comment: Done, do you have any approaching advice?

Comment: Questions which simply demand a proof, without showing any of your own work, can easily attract close votes. To avoid this fate, take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on the section for [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your question is missing some important context, for example: What have you tried? What happened when you wrote out the given linear system and attempted to apply it to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**No linear homogeneous system can have a set of solutions $S$ of this form**.

Indeed the solution set of a homogeneous linear system is a vector space, in particular is stable by scalar multiplication.

But, here is a counterexample: taking $a=b=1$, $(1,1,1) \in S$ whereas its double  $2*(1,1,1)=(2,2,2) \notin S$ because the second coordinate isn't the square of the first one.